Failed to update help in windows powershell
I am an absolute beginner to Command Line Interface and noticed this when trying to update the help (I'm following Learn Enough Command Line to Be Dangerous, which I suppose is for Linux and I am using Windows).This is how my PowerShell looks
I was expecting it would update the help manual(ig that is what it is called).

1st: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  2nd: Please do not use (sole) images of code/data/errors in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question (use [edit] button), then format it as code. 3rd: Read and follow the message hint to Run as Administrator…

You are correct that "Learn Enough Command Line to Be Dangerous" is written for *NIX shells. Although it never mentions bash, ksh, or anything else. Their answer to using Windows is to install WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). That will not teach you PowerShell.

You have to start PowerShell as an Administrator.
If you have a look at the error-messages it at lines 10/11. You are getting an "Access is denied" message there which also tells you how to fix it.
I understand you are getting overwhelmed by such a long error message when you just start your PowerShell journey. My advice would be to do read them anyway since they often will give you a lot of insight.
